# Facebook share og:image incorrect. Debugger is picking up the correct image

Tags: wordpress, facebook, debugging

The past week, Facebook has been getting every article feature image wrong on my site. The og:image is clearly defined, worked fine for the past few months and even the debugger shows the correct image, yet it chooses to use the same incorrect image across all new articles now.

Article
**http://www.highwaysindustry.com/causeway-creating-a-competitive-edge/**

Facebook Debugger:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
URL: **http://www.highwaysindustry.com/causeway-creating-a-competitive-edge/**

The meta tag, which clearly provides/defines the correct image Facebook should be using:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.highwaysindustry.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Causeway-image-1.jpg" />
```

When on the debugger, if you **Fetch New Scrape Information** it will fix the issue. However I am currently having to do this on every single article that is posted. Why it's getting the wrong image in the first place I don't know.

In case someone runs the 'fetch new scrape information', here it is at the moment for that URL provided:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8t4o9h3o1p9uxhv/debugger-fb.png?dl=0

[image]

I am using WordPress and Yoast SEO.

Comment: Try specifying width and height of the image upfront, as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#precaching

Answer (score 0):

There's a warning. And it's going to take some time to update the latest information but for now you might have to fetch new scrape information yourself.

> og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook. Image 'http://www.highwaysindustry.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Dorman00001-e1423681471392.jpg' will be used instead.

Comment: I've clearly stated that the og:image tag is present, has been for the entire time the website has been live. And the image is larger than 200x200 as required.

New articles are posted every few hours. It's when these new articles which are published I check on, without fail they immediately use the incorrect image, some default image Facebook seems to have selected.